# Statistics that are neither auto_created nor user_created

Tags: sql-server, statistics, index-statistics

So far, I was under the impression that there are two types of statistics objects in SQL Server:

- **automatically-created statistics**, which are created by SQL Server on index columns or single columns to improve performance, and
- **user-created statistics**, which are created manually with a `CREATE STATISTICS` statement.

Thus, I was quite surprised to see the following query:

```
SELECT s.name, s.stats_id, s.auto_created, s.user_created
  FROM sys.stats AS s
       INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc ON s.object_id = sc.object_id AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id
       INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND sc.column_id = c.column_id
       INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
 WHERE t.name = 'mytable'
```

yield the following result:

```
name                    stats_id   auto_created   user_created
--------------------------------------------------------------
PK__mytable__7A73B1B8       1          0              0
SomeIndex                   2          0              0
SomeIndexedColumn1          3          0              0
SomeIndexedColumn2          4          0              0
SomeIndexedColumn3          5          0              0
SomeColumn                  6          0              1
```

What are those statistics, which are neither auto_created nor user_created? I've looked at [the documentation of sys.stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177623.aspx), but did not find an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are statistics created with the creation of an index.

I guess they somehow infer that the statistics haven't been created as statistics but as a side effect of an index.

I've noticed this in my databases before and they just seem to always be index-related. I can't find any documentation proving this though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes statistics can be created in 3 ways:

1) Statistics created due to index creation. These statistics have the index name

2) Statistics created by Optimizer(Column statistics). Starts with *WA**

3) User defined statistics which are created with CREATE STATISTICS command by the DBA

ref : https://harshdba.wordpress.com/category/sql-server-statistics/